# Node.js module require dependency issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, require, javascript-objects

I have a simple Node.js-powered custom static site generator setup, I pass it two options, a simple template and a some JSON for the site data. I have the following data files:

```
// collections.js

var collection = require('./collection');

module.exports = [
  collection
]


// collection.js

var product = require('./product');

module.exports = {
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Collection",
  "products": [
    product
  ]
}


// product.js

var collections = require('./collections');

module.exports = {
  "id": 4759071046,
  "title": "Product",
  "collections": collections,
  "price": 2000,
  "content": "This is a test product."
};
```

EDIT: This isn't one big file with multiple `module.exports`, they're separate files; when you see `// collections.js`, this signifies that it's a separate file called collections.js, when you see `// collection.js`, this signifies that it's a separate file called collection.js and when you see `// product.js`, this signifies that it's a separate file called product.js

I'm quite new to module loading via `​​require()` so I think I've got some kind of dependency loop error going on somewhere but I get no errors, just incorrect data structures when I `console.log()` the data:

```
// collections.js

[  
   {  
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Collection",
      "products": [  
         {  

         }
      ]
   }
]


// collection.js

{  
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Collection",
  "products": [  
     {  

     }
  ]
}


// product.js

{  
   "id": 4759071046,
   "title": "Product",
   "collections": [  
      {  
         "id": 1,
         "title": "Collection",
         "products": [  
            {  

            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "price": 2000,
   "content": "This is a test product."
}
```

Notice the empty `products` object array? I have no idea why this is happening, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you've definitely got a circular dependency here. Why do you use this weird object layout?

Comment: You've got a circular dependency here. Product requires collections, collections requires collection, collection requires product, etc., etc. Figure out what your top-level object is supposed to be and then what it's supposed to contain.

Answer (score 0):

If you ran "node collections" from the command line, this would execute the code within the collections.js file. (assuming you were in the same directory)

When node see something like var collection = require('./someFile'), it will execute the code in someFile.  If someFile has a require statement, node will then execute the code contained within the file that is passed within that require statement.

As noted below, this process will happen once for every file that is required, so it is important to keep that into consideration even if you aren't using the imported objects.

Comment: It won't go on forever, because node only requires each module once, but it won't return the expected value either.